# Hibernate - How to write criteria or sql or hql query for combined properties?

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api, native-sql

I've stored the full name of the individual as firstName, middleName & lastName differently on the datastore.

The user enters the full name to search the individual.
The problem is I want to search firstName, middleName & lastName combinedly.

And, I can't make the tokens of full name as there may be embedded spaces.
Please help me. This is killing me.

Comment: can you clarify your purpose more than that pleaz ??

Answer (score 0):

In your model make a new getter

```
Public String getFullName(){
    return firstName+" "+middleName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Now use this in hibernate

```
hql="From User u where fullName="+fullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Formula

```
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Formula(value = "first_name + ' ' + last_name")
private String name;
```

then you can query on the name property as if it was a column in your table